# Implementing K-Gram indexing in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, database-indexes, pg-trgm

I am trying to implement an index in postgres for wild card queries such as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE COL1 LIKE '<text>%';
```

I know postgres offers gin and gist trigram indexing through pg_trgm extension. But, it stores the trigrams of the text in the index value.
is there any way I can modify the implementation from trigram to digram or n-gram where n can be modified, in postgres ?
It would be much preferred if there is a way to do it with GIN indexing. if not, any other alternatives are also much welcomed.

Comment: You can modify the source code of pg_trgm and recompile it, assuming you can code in C. The problem would be getting the original version and the hacked version to live together nicely, if that is needed.  But why? Is this just curiosity, or are you trying to accomplish something practical?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @jjanes. I am trying to build an autocomplete feature and using a partial search with like operator. Gin index has added more speed in retrieving the results. I want it to use gin index and work as fast even when the user has only given 2 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the pattern doesn't start with a wild card (which your example suggests is true), trigrams should still work. For example, the pattern 'th%' will generate the bigram-like trigram ' th'.

If your true pattern is such as '%th%', that would generate no trigrams, but auto completion starting into the middle of words generally doesn't make sense so i would reconsider doing it that way.